# How Prometheus cab add a fix value label when scraping

Tags: prometheus

Actually, I want to add a label referring to the cluster name to all metrics , just like:

k8s_cluster_name=cluster01,

I do not find an actioncan do this.

/wangyu

Comment: Sounds like you should check out relabelling https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Crelabel_config%3E

Comment: yes, I checked, but I do not find relevant actions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this label to all metrics exposed on a single Prometheus instance you may go for `external_labels`:

```
global:
  external_labels:
    k8s_cluster_name: 'cluster01'
```

Otherwise you'll need to deal with relabeling.